# Id unico de hardware

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aplicación-web, asp, hardware

Tengo una aplicación en asp con c# tienen un login el cual me lleva a un menú responsivo validando la seguridad por medio de roles, pero ese no es el problema, resulta que las personas que quieren las validaciones necesitan que en una tabla guarde los id únicos del disco, tarjeta madre y disco duro así cuando se logen ademas de leer los usuario tambien lea estos ID y si no estan registrador muestre un mensaje que no esta autorizado a usar la app

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: Por otro lado no veo mucho sentido que el hardware de un equipo sea parte de la seguridad, un usuario puede cambiar en cualquier momento su tarjeta de red, su placa base o su tarjeta gráfica.

Comment: El navegador no puede acceder al hardware del equipo en el que está por motivos de seguridad.

Comment: creamos una app en asp, es para una empresa de entrega de mercancía, ellos pagaron por el uso de una licencia solo para unas de sus bodegas si funcionara como ellos quieren pagarían por el uso de las demás bodegas, la gente que negocio esto quiere que la app solo corra en 3 pc por así decirlo que son las necesaria para que se maneje el proceso, pero no quiere que dentro se pueda usar en otras pc, por lo tanto quieren guardar el id del disco,el procesador y la placa madre las 3 de cada maquina, y cuando se logeen revise si esta pc esta dentro de la validacion de lo contrario no pasara del login

Comment: Pues has los clientes en windows (Windows Forms o WPF).